# When i do the login i should change the page

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

**Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference**

```
Accesso(){
    $.get("http://localhost:4000/utente?matricola="+this.username+"&password="+this.pass)
    .done(function(data){
        if(data=="Errore")
            alert("Errore");
        else{
            alert("success - "+data);
            this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage[0]);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(data){
        alert("error- " + data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where you define navCtrl?

Comment: In the export class LoginPage

Comment: Constructor(publish navCtrl: NavController){}

Comment: public not publish correct it

Comment: I was wrong while I was writing the comment

Answer (score 0):

In .done(function(data){}) the scope of ***this*** is changed so, you did not get this.navCtrl. so, the solution is to use arrow operator in done function instead of function it will solve your issue.

```
Accesso(){
    $.get("http://localhost:4000/utente?matricola="+this.username+"&password="+this.pass)
    .done((data)=>{
        if(data=="Errore")
            alert("Errore");
        else{
            alert("success - "+data);
            this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage[0]);
        }
    })
    .fail((data)=>{
        alert("error- " + data);
    });
}
```

Comment: thats but i don't know,how to use?

Comment: Just remove function word and write data=>{} that's it . I will do code but right now i am using mobile and i am not able to format code.

Comment: Now there is another mistake

Comment: unchaught (in promise): invalid views to insert

Comment: This issue in your TabPage array

Comment: Arrow operator solved your this issue Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference

Comment: If this answer solved your push issue then accept it.